# Mozilla addons not working properly in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: firefox, plugins

I have encountered a problem in Mozilla. I am unable to install/uninstall the plugins. I don't why it is happening. :( I am using Ubuntu 12.04. Please help me out

Comment: Which plugin/addon were you unable to install/uninstall?

Answer (score 1):

(I assume you are using `firefox`, but most of these troubleshooting steps like safe-mode will work for `Thunderbird` as well, so they should still be useful)

**Don't** delete your profile folder straightaway as there's a lot more you can do before you do something like that. There are several ways of resetting your `firefox` data.

**1**) Try going to help > troubleshooting and you will see this screen (do not go to `about:support` without going through the menu or the reset option won't be available):

[image]

Just click the reset option and `firefox` will be returned to its initial state. I have just tested this and it does reset settings and uninstall addons, while retaining your bookmarks.

**2**) Use the special `-safe-mode` option to load `firefox` (this works with `Thunderbird` as well) Run from terminal,

```
firefox -safe-mode
```

You will receive a box like this, which should allow you to load `firefox` and see if it was an addon that was causing the abnormal behaviour. Restart `firefox` in safe-mode again a second time and this time click the left-hand reset button if you want to clear your settings and addons.

[image]

**3**) If neither of these suggestions sorts your problem out, you could run profilemanager and create a new profile and run `firefox` from that.

```
firefox -ProfileManager -no-remote
```

[image]

Then you could launch `firefox` like this or create a new shortcut, giving the exact location of your new profile:

```
firefox -Profile /home/mike/.mozilla/firefox/55divdmr.Mike2 -no-remote
```

For more on using different profiles in firefox, please see my answer here:

- [How to create shortcuts to different Firefox profiles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226335/how-to-create-shortcuts-to-different-firefox-profiles/)

In addition, when you create a new profile, our old profile will not be deleted, so you will still have the data and bookmarks. However, you could set the new profile as your default by placing `Default=1` under your desired profile in `~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini`.

You could backup your bookmarks to a html file with your old profile by going to firefox > bookmarks > import & backup > export to html. You could then import these when you have launched your new profile.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something in you settings folder got corrupt.

You may delete it (you will loose bookmarks, history, saved passwords, extensions).

1. Close Firefox.
2. Open Nautilus, press ctrl + H to show hidden folders
3. Find the `.mozilla` folder and delete it.
4. Open Firefox (it should be like a fresh install)