# How to fix Firefox in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, firefox

This only happens with Firefox. Everything else runs fine. Some specs:

- My computer is a Dell Demension C521;
- Graphics: Nvidia GeForce 6150 LE Card

How can i debug and fix the problem?

Comment: Can you describe the actual problem in more details, while leaving out all the irrelevant info you've posted above.

Comment: Also what you mean with "freezes"? Your system stays completely unresponsive or you can use Ctrl+Alt+F1 for example or [Alt+SysRq+REISUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)? The disk usage led (if there's any) stays on? With just the info you provided it will be difficult to someone help you.

Comment: The Computer Doesnt Freeze But Fire Fox Does. i really dont know how to explain it. I Guess It Takes Forever to start up. Then When It Does Start up It takes Forever to load any web page. Then I Can See The spinning arrow on the tab indicating that the page is loading stop completely then it starts again and finally loads. Then it takes a while before I can click on any links posted on the page then when i click on a link the new page takes forever to load and so on and so forth. please help..... Thanks

Comment: My answer [for this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/228222/mozilla-addons-not-working-properly-in-ubuntu-12-04) might well help, as I go through general troubleshooting procedures relating to `Firefox`.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bug with nvidia & firefox issue. It happens on my Win 8 64but machine as well. Firefox 17 no issue, FF18 slow issue, then nvidia came out latest driver 314.07 issue is gone but once FF19 comes out issue is back. It stands to reason must be a link with FF & Nvidia.