# Firefox constantly crashes no log

Tags: 12.10, firefox

I have Ubuntu 12.10 and it most of times crashes. I've disabled all plugins, resetted firefox, started in safe-mode, but still crashes. It even crashes in safe-mode after firefox reset.

I also did firefox purge via apt-get and re-installed it after cleaning apt-cache (re-download), still crashes...

Sometimes crashes becomes constant, I mean, it crashes right after I click on firefox icon, then I press quit, re-click on firefox icon ONLY, crash!, re-click crash! etc.

I checked /var/log/syslog and dmesg, can't find anything related to firefox or mozilla.

Please advice.

Comment: Make sure Firefox isn't running. Then rename `~/.mozilla` to something else and see if Firefox still crashes.

Comment: I should run firefox from terminal, and post the results here. There might be something useful in that output. Also, see the options listed in answers for [this question here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/228222/mozilla-addons-not-working-properly-in-ubuntu-12-04). Try a new firefox profile, for example.

Comment: I deleted my .mozilla folder, deleted apt-get cache, re-installed firefox, nothing changes. When I run it from console, I was looking for something useful too, but nothing at all! No error in console, no anything related to problem in console.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your local package index by running `apt-get update` before you reinstall Firefox. This will make sure you're installing the latest version.

There is [a Firefox help page](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-crashes-troubleshoot-prevent-and-get-help) containing several suggestions for debugging Firfox crashes. Here are some of its suggestions:

- Update Firefox | see above
- Update Linux and drivers | run a full system upgrade by running `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`
- Check you RAM | on boot, hold shift when GRUB comes up and run a memory test.

Comment: `apt-get purge` does *not* remove files in /home. It only removes system config files (in addition to whatever `apt-get remove` removes). So you may want to modify the currently last sentence to something more appropriate.

Comment: I cleared apt-get cache, my Ubuntu is up to date and have no available update package, then re-installed firefox, nothing changes...

Comment: I have removed the note entirely.

I'm a bit new here. Is my answer considered acceptable or should it have been a comment?